# What should be used instead of UseGoogleAuthentication Method (IAppBuilder)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, oauth

The MSDN documentation [states](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn253576%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) that:

> GoogleAuthenticationExtensions.UseGoogleAuthentication Method
>   (IAppBuilder)
>
> Note: This API is now **obsolete**.

What's the alternative? What should be used instead of this method?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/owin.googleauthenticationextensions.usegoogleauthentication%28v=vs.113%29.aspx probably the Oauth ones?

Comment: @DaImTo Yes, that should be it.

Comment: might want to consider the Google .net client lib BTW.  I haven't bothered with the msn ones.   Love to hear how they work though.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Google OAuth2 middleware like this:

```
private void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var cookieOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
    };

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(cookieOptions);

    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(cookieOptions.AuthenticationType);

    app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
    {
        ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"],
        ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"]
    });
}
```

You can create a client id and secret at: https://console.developers.google.com/